# Django-allauth: Facebook popup showing progress bar

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, django-allauth, facebook-social-plugins

I am integrating django-allauth on my application for login/signup with facebook. Opened facebook popup showing progess bar. So how can I hide that ?
[image]

Comment: Are you explicitly asking the user to re-enter their password, or how did you get to that specific dialog?

Comment: Yes, i am asking to re-enter password.

Comment: Can i disabled to re-enter password?

Comment: If you are explicitly asking for it via the auth_type parameter … well, then don’t?